# Переадресация всех папок, кроме одной, с помощью .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Существует сайт, допустим pul.ru, нужно настроить переадресацию в файле .htaccess так, чтобы все запросы на сайт кроме определенных переадресовывались в 1 папку.

Например:

```
pul.ru/trololo
pul.ru/sr
pul.ru/ad
```

Вcе это переадресовывалось в `pul.ru/index/`

Кроме `pul.ru/src/` и всех последующих путей (`pul.ru/src/trtrt/`, `pul.ru/src/hhghg`) и т.д.

Comment: поиском пользовались?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалось проверить на своем сервере.
Вот такое у меня работало правильно

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/media/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index/index.htm [L,QSA]
```

Если переводить это в Ваш пример, вот это должно работать

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/src/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index/index.php?request=$1
```

Что у Вас в папке index? надо указать запускающий файл... `index.php`? или что-то?

Comment: Увы, Internal Server Error

Comment: Обновил ответ... еще раз проверьте

Comment: Тоже самое, Internal Server Error

Comment: Дурацкий вопрос: а вы `pul.ru` меняли на реальный домен?

Comment: Ответ на дурацкий вопрос: Да.

Comment: В итоге заработало в таком виде:

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/src/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index/index.php [L,QSA]

Comment: ОК, ну чудесно... Александр, будьте добры, либо пометьте вопрос как отмеченный (галочка на ответе), либо оформите окончательный вариант как "Ответ на свой вопрос". Это даст нам возможность закрыть вопрос - а-то тут много незакрытых, но отвеченных вопросов. Радею за статистику сообщества :):):):) Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент заработало вот таким вот образом

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/src/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index/index.php [L,QSA]
```

Чтобы не создавать новую тему, может кто подскажет, проверил значение переменной `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` в `index.php` (сюда идут все переадресации) и она оказалась пуста, хотя по идее в ней должен быть путь, откуда кинуло.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` - не дает 100% гарантии, что там будут данные. Вот тут расписаны условия (русского варианта не нашел) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880659/in-what-cases-will-http-referer-be-empty

Comment: галочку на ответе поставьте, пожалуйста